# Does Exim 4.94 in Debian 11 have no DMARC/SPF support?

Tags: debian, spf, dmarc, exim4

I had Debian 9 server with exim4-daemon-heavy which supported SPF and DMARC. After upgrade to Debian 11 I see that exim4-daemon-heavy does no longer assume supporting those features. Looks like a bad joke. But maybe I don't know something.

Could you please advice how to use or maybe configure SPF and DMARC support in fresh versions of Exim4 in Debian.

p.s. I mean except building exim4 from sources.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At least in terms of SPF, no, it doesn't.

The [wiki page explains](https://wiki.debian.org/PkgExim4UserFAQ#Why_are_you_not_using_exim.27s_built-in_SPF_interface.3F):

> #### 1.8.2. Why are you not using exim's built-in SPF interface?
>
> exiscan 4.34-22 introduced support for the [Sender Policy
> Framework](http://www.openspf.org) by means of a spf
>
> ACL condition. We have chosen not to use this command, but implement
> this functionality in the Debian packages by means of external calls
> to [spfquery](https://packages.debian.org/spf-tools-perl)
>
> Rationale:
>
> - Calling spfquery is a reliable method, because it's the most transparent and easy to debug. It is also the method we have tested
>   more thoroughly and are most experienced with.
> - We do not want to drag in another library dependency. That would add more potential for bugs and maintenance work than a configuration
>   snippet that is disabled by default.
> - We haven't verified that all the features of spfquery are available using built-in support as well (in particular, support for X-SPF-Guess
>   header, or the ability to add user extensions that rely on the same
>   checks).
>
> If you'd rather use exiscan's own SPF interface, you need to rebuild
> exim. The source package offers infrastructure to build your own
> exim4-daemon-custom with your own feature set.

Perhaps more helpfully, if you would *like* SPF support it you only need to

```
# as root
apt install spf-tools-perl
```

Then, I have a file at /etc/exim4/conf.d/01a_exim4-config_custom into which I put:

```
# Reject failed SPF
CHECK_RCPT_SPF=true
```

That variable (macro?) is checked in `acl/30_exim4-config_check_rcpt`

Nb. if you use the combined file aproach, instead of split config files you'll need to dig for the right place for this. Also remember to run `systemctl stop exim4; update-exim4.conf; systemctl start exim4` after editing.